# Dual Monitor VLC Issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player

I have a strange issue. It's not causing me to lose sleep, but it is quite annoying.

I'm running dual monitors successfully for over a year on Windows 7. And my applications remember their previous windows position & size, including which monitor they display on.

Except for VLC. And this is just within the last few weeks. It keeps swapping monitors. If I start it, it shows up maximized on monitor 1. If I close it, and reopen it, it shows up maximized on monitor 2. The next time will be back on monitor 1 again.
It's not random. It literally swaps monitors every time it's open.

I would like it to stay on monitor 1, as that shows a better picture and has a wider screen. Any ideas here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with remote dekstop windows, I solved it by using [ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)

It's a utility for multi-monitor systems, designed to increase productivity and unlock the full potential of multiple monitors:

1. efficiently move windows and maximize windows across the desktop
2. manage more applications with the Smart Taskbar
3. control application positioning with UltraMon Shortcuts
4. multi-monitor support for desktop wallpapers and screen savers
5. mirror your main monitor to secondary monitors for a presentation